# empty ProcessBuilder InputStream

Tags: java, processbuilder, gnupg

I have some problems using the java ProcessBuilder.
I want to get my gpg keys, so I use the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\[path]\\GnuPG\\pub\\gpg.exe", "--list-keys");
    //builder.directory(new File("C:\\[path]\\GnuPG\\pub\\"));
    Process process = builder.start();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(process.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\Z");
    System.out.println(s.next());
    s.close();
```

But I always get a NoSuchElementException when executing s.next().
If I use the gpg command "-h", I always get the expected output.

If I change the Constructor call to

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "C:\\[path]\\GnuPG\\pub\\gpg.exe", "--list-keys");
```

it sometimes works. But most times it doesn´t.

WHY? Can anyone help? THANKS!!

Comment: Anything in `process.getErrorStream()`?

Comment: Does it help if you set `builder.redirectErrorStream(true);`?  That redirects the process's standard error stream into its standard output stream without you needing to read from the error stream in a separate thread.

Comment: No - nothing in error stream. Also redirect doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
    Test test = new Test();
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("C:\\[path]\\GnuPG\\pub\\gpg.exe");
    commands.add("--list-keys");
    test.doCommand(commands);
}


public void doCommand(List<String> command) 
throws IOException
{
    String s = null;

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = pb.start();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader  
    (process.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
    (process.getErrorStream()));

    StringBuffer start= new StringBuffer();

    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
    {
        start.append(s);
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
    stdInput.close();

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
    {
        start.append(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good start, but I just get an empty line after "Here is the standard output of the command".
If I add the lines

commands.add("cmd");
commands.add("/c");

it´s the same as before. Sometimes I get a Response, sometimes not.